# Me marca error con entity al tratar de probar mi publicacion de Net core

Tags: windows, entity-framework, cmd, .net-core, publish

Actualmente tengo un proyecto de Net core al cual le hice una publicacion y me exporto todos mis dll's y demas archivos en una carpeta de bin, pero al intentar correr el dll principal me sale un error, el comando que ejecuto para probar si el el proyecto se publico bien es el siguiente.

```
dotnet ProyectoGasera.Web.dll
```

El resultado que me sale es el siguiente:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (136ms) [Parameters=[@__normalizedName_0='ADMINISTRADOR' (Size = 256)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT `a`.`Id`, `a`.`ConcurrencyStamp`, `a`.`Name`, `a`.`NormalizedName`
      FROM `AspNetRoles` AS `a`
      WHERE `a`.`NormalizedName` = @__normalizedName_0
      LIMIT 1
```

Me gustaria saber porque me sale ese error y a que se puede deber, ya que despues de ejecutarlo y saber que se publico correctamente pienso subirlo a un servidor de Linux con distribucion de debian.

Dejo otra parte del error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'ProyectoGasera.DataAccess.DataContext'.
      MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'appgasolineradb.AspNetRoles' doesn't exist
         at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask`1 task) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 888
         at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 50
         at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 135
         at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 444
         at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 60
         at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 314
         at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 307
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
      MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'appgasolineradb.AspNetRoles' doesn't exist
         at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask`1 task) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 888
         at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 50
         at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnectUnhandled exception.or/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 135
         at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavi or ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 444
         at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 60
         at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 314
         at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 307
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Table 'appgasolineradb.AspNetRoles' doesn't exist)
 ---> MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'appgasolineradb.AspNetRoles' doesn't exist
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.ReceiveReplyAsyncAwaited(ValueTask`1 task) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ServerSession.cs:line 888
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 50
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 135
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 444
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 60
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 314
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 307
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1.RoleExistsAsync(String roleName)
   at ProyectoGasera.DataAccess.Core.UserHelper.CheckRoleAsync(String roleName) in C:\proyectos\AppGasera\Gasera_2\ProyectoGasera.DataAccess\Core\UserHelper.cs:line 45
   at ProyectoGasera.DataAccess.SeedDb.CheckRolesAsync() in C:\proyectos\AppGasera\Gasera_2\ProyectoGasera.DataAccess\SeedDb.cs:line 74
   at ProyectoGasera.DataAccess.SeedDb.SeedAsync() in C:\proyectos\AppGasera\Gasera_2\ProyectoGasera.DataAccess\SeedDb.cs:line 25
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at ProyectoGasera.Web.Program.RunSeeding(IWebHost host) in C:\proyectos\AppGasera\Gasera_2\ProyectoGasera.Web\Program.cs:line 36
   at ProyectoGasera.Web.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\proyectos\AppGasera\Gasera_2\ProyectoGasera.Web\Program.cs:line 26
```

Comment: ¿Y sólo esa traza del error te muestra? Normalmente luego de eso te pone los detalles que causaron el error. ¿Adjuntaste tu traza completa?

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez ya actualice el post con toda la traza completa del error que me sale en consola.

Comment: Bueno, el error es bastante claro ahora, `Table 'appgasolineradb.AspNetRoles' doesn't exist`. La tabla `'appgasolineradb.AspNetRoles'` no existe.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez que raro, si esta en mi base de datos pero en minusculas y creo que puede ser eso, pero si lo ejecuto con IIS si funciona correctamente.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que los nombre matchean exactamente? ¿Lo estás ejecutando en linux? Según estuve leyendo, Mysql es case sensitive dependiendo del sistema operativo en el que opera. Las rutas en windows son case insensitive, por lo que es normal que te funcionara con IIS pero en linux no son case insensitive, lo cuál explica este error. Checa si haciendo un cambio de nombres se soluciona el problema.